# When can I start contributing to my Spousal RRSP again without attribution implications?

Tags: income-tax, canada, contribution, rrsp, withdrawal

I have a question about the Spousal RRSP that I want to validate.

When can you **start** contributing back to a Spousal RRSP after a withdrawal has been made?

**Summary of actions taken so far:**

- My last contribution was in **December 2012**.
- I made a withdrawal (partial de-registration) in **January 2016**.

**As I understand it:**

Any withdrawals from ***Jan 1, 2015*** are attributed as income to my spouse.

- 2012 (last deposit)
- 2013 (no activity)
- 2014 (no activity)
- 2015 (no activity)
- 2016 (withdrawal) - Deposits in 2014, 2015, and 2016 ($0) attribute to **me**  as income

So, my spouse will have income for the 2016 tax year from the SRRSP withdrawal.

## Are the following assumptions correct:

1. I **should not** (unfortunately) make a contribution in **calendar year** 2016 even though the contribution would be **after** the date she withdrew ( Jan 2016 ) to avoid it being attributed to me.
2. I **can** still contribute in Jan-Feb 2017 and it will count as a deduction for the **2016** tax year
3. I **can** contribute in Mar-Dec 2017 and it will count as a deduction for the **2017** tax year

I'm 80% sure about point 1, 99% sure about point 3. And I'm 50% sure about point 2.

Note: My assumptions are based on [this from the CRA](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/tg/t4040/t4040-e.html#cal_income) and [here](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/tp/it307r4/it307r4-e.html).